Can't set theme in shiny using bslib
I'm trying to set a new theme for my shiny app using bslib with some additional rules for the accordion header. I don't see any difference, why is that?
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

theme = bs_theme(bg = "black", fg = "white") |> 
  bs_add_rules(".accordion-title {
    color: red;
    font-family: 'Lucida Console', 'Courier New', monospace;
    }")

ui <- 
page_fillable(
  page_fluid(
    page_sidebar(
      theme = theme,
      sidebar = bslib::accordion(accordion_panel("Options"))
    ),
  ))


shinyApp(ui, function(input, output, session){})


library(shiny)
library(bslib)

theme <- bs_theme(bg = "black", fg = "white") |> 
bs_add_rules(".accordion-title {
color: red;
font-family: 'Lucida Console', 'Courier New', monospace;
}")

ui <- 
page_fillable(
theme = theme,
page_fluid(
page_sidebar(
  
  sidebar = bslib::accordion(accordion_panel("Options"))
),
))


shinyApp(ui, function(input, output, session){})


This does not work at all.

my bad ,try this version
